# Need XSLT for merging two xml files

Tags: xml, xslt

File Structure:
Both File1.xml and File2.xml has same structure.

File has list/array of resources and each resource has list/array of codes.

Each code is uniquely identified by "id" attribute.

Each code has "override" attribute which specifies overriding rule.

If override="true" then the code element in file1.xml can be replaced with code element in file2.xml.

I want to merge File1.xml with File2.xml using xslt with below rules

1. If both files has same resource name (Eg: "resource1") then there codes can be merged.

   During merge operation if we have same "id" value then file1 code element can be replaced with file2 code element ONLY when override="true".

   ```
   <code id="1" field1="value11" field2="value12" override="true" />
   <code id="1" field1="value71" field2="value72" override="true" />

   For this the result should be 
   <code id="1" field1="value71" field2="value72" override="true" />
   ```

   If override="false" then we don't replace code element.

   <code id="2" field1="value21" field2="value22" override="false" />

   <code id="2" field1="value81" field2="value82" override="true" />

   For this the result should be

   <code id="2" field1="value21" field2="value22" override="false" />
2. If we have distinct resource names (Eg: resource2 in File1.xml and resource3 in File2.xml) then those can be written as it is in output.xml as
   there is nothing to be merged between files.

   Thank You so much for showing interest in my question!!!

File1.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource name="resource1">
        <codes>
            <code id="1" field1="value11" field2="value12" override="true" />
            <code id="2" field1="value21" field2="value22" override="false" />
            <code id="3" field1="value31" field2="value32" override="true" />
        </codes>
    </resource>
    <resource name="resource2">
        <codes>
            <code id="1" field1="value11" field2="value12" override="true" />
        </codes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

File2.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource name="resource1">
        <codes>
            <code id="1" field1="value71" field2="value72" override="true" />
            <code id="2" field1="value81" field2="value82" override="true" />
            <code id="4" field1="value91" field2="value92" override="true" />
        </codes>
    </resource>
    <resource name="resource3">
        <codes>
            <code id="2" field1="value81" field2="value82" override="true" />
        </codes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

output.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource name="resource1">
        <codes>
            <code id="1" field1="value71" field2="value72" override="true" />
            <code id="2" field1="value21" field2="value22" override="false" />
            <code id="3" field1="value31" field2="value32" override="true" />
            <code id="4" field1="value91" field2="value92" override="true" />
        </codes>
    </resource>
    <resource name="resource2">
        <codes>
            <code id="1" field1="value11" field2="value12" override="true" />
        </codes>
    </resource>
    <resource name="resource3">
        <codes>
            <code id="2" field1="value81" field2="value82" override="true" />
        </codes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Which XSLT version, which XSLT processor do you use? Are those `code` elements ordered by the `id` integer attribute value, as in the samples?

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0, id is not ordered

Comment: I am using below java code for doing XSLT transformation in java  TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xslt"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));

Comment: Where is your attempted xslt code? Please post the errors or undesired results?

Comment: I am new to xslt, I tried examples on w3c site but not able to write xslt for my use case.

Comment: As you have shown us some Java code to run the XSLT it seems you are in a position to move to Saxon 9 and use XSLT 2 or 3 to have an easier approach on the XSLT side. At please post well-formed XML snippets to start with, after your edit you have unclosed attribute values like `name="resource1`, unclosed start tags `<resource>`.

Comment: Furthermore it is not clear whether the final `resource` with `name` as `resource3` really doesn't have any `codes` child element or you forgot to insert that into the sample, if your input is that irregular it is sufficient to post some samples to have us guess the rules for the transformation, you will need to explain in plain English what kind of merging rules you want to implement for which elements exactly.

Comment: My Bad I written  these xml's in notepad, I reposted. Please let me know if you need any more information. Thank You @Martin Honnen

Comment: As I said, as you use Java you can easily switch to Saxon 9 (available in the open-source HE edition on Maven and Sourceforge) and then you can use XSLT 2 or 3 to solve that instead of only using XSLT 1 as supported by the Oracle/Apache Xalan processor. An example of XSLT 3 is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNn/2. There the second document is used as a parameter inlined but of course you could pass in the URI of the second file and use e.g. `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc("file2.xml")"/>` instead.

Comment: Thanks Martin! This xslt replaced 200 lines of Java Code. Xslt is not getting resource name attribute in the output. I tried to add the attribute but I am getting error "Attribute name ${v1} is not a valid QName". can you please check. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtr9

Comment: I got the solution for adding resource name attribute 
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBub
Thank You so much Martin!!! for guiding me, do we have any free/paid courses available to learn xslt in depth.

Comment: @LeelaPrasad, good that you tried to move to XSLT 3 and worked your way through some trial and error to find a working solution, see also https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBub/1 how you could preserve the `name` attribute of the `resource` element in a more compact way. I have inserted my previous suggestions made in comments into an answer so that you can mark your question as solved.

Comment: Thanks Martin!!!

Comment: I am not able to upvote your answer as I have less score in stack overflow, but your answer helped me a lot. I checked the tick button and assume that is the to mark a question as solved, if not can you please let me know how to mark a question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you seem to use Java to run XSLT you could consider to use Saxon 9 (available for Java in the open-source HE edition on Maven (current latest release of Saxon 9.9 HE is at https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.9.0-2/jar, of Saxon 9.8 HE at https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.sf.saxon/Saxon-HE/9.8.0-14/jar) and Sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/) to then use XSLT 3 or 2 instead of the twenty year old XSLT 1 the built-in Oracle/Apache Xalan processor supports.

Using XSLT 3 you can treat that as a nested grouping problem as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="doc2">
<resources>
    <resource name="resource1">
        <codes>
            <code id="1" field1="value71" field2="value72" override="true" />
            <code id="2" field1="value81" field2="value82" override="true" />
            <code id="4" field1="value91" field2="value92" override="true" /> 
        </codes>
    </resource>
    <resource name="resource3">
        <codes>
            <code id="2" field1="value81" field2="value82" override="true" />
        </codes>
    </resource>
</resources>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="resources">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="resource, $doc2/resources/resource" group-by="@name">
              <resource>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                  <codes>
                      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()!codes/code" group-by="@id">
                          <xsl:apply-templates
                            select="if (current-group()[2] and ./@override = 'true')
                                    then current-group()[2]
                                    else ."/>
                      </xsl:for-each-group>
                  </codes>
              </resource>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rNn/3 has an online sample, there for compactness and completeness of the example the second document is used as a parameter inlined but of course you could pass in the URI of the second file and use e.g. `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc("file2.xml")"/>` instead.

As for introductions to XSLT, a free book "Practical Transformation Using XSLT and XPath" is available at https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm.